# Map array of dictionaries to select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to map an array of dictionaries to a select dropdown, but my current approach just yields the correct number of select options with no values.

```
This is what my array looks like:
dateArray = [
      {year:'2016', month: "01"},
      {year:'2017', month: "01"},
      {year:'2018', month: "02"},
      {year:'2018', month: "02"}
    ];
```

This is how I am trying to map the array to the select dropdowns:

```
            <select className='form-control'>
              {this.state.dateArray.map((year) => <option key={year.value} value={year.value}>{year.display}</option>)}
            </select>
            <select className='form-control'>
              {this.state.dateArray.map((month) => <option key={month.value} value={month.value}>{month.display}</option>)}
            </select>
```

How can I map my array of dictionaries to select dropdowns?

Comment: I could do this easily with something like `ejs` or `django-templates`, but I have no idea how to use reactjs!  If you think it would be helpful I can show you, although I'm doubtful it would be.

Comment: You can easily use a foreach loop. You would have to modify the document using DOM though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work:

```
<select className='form-control'>
  {this.state.dateArray.map((item, i) => {return <option key={i} value={item.year}>{item.year}</option>})}
</select>
<select className='form-control'>
  {this.state.dateArray.map((item, i) => {return <option key={i} value={item.month}>{item.month}</option>})}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code using a [`.foreach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop to loop through the array, and [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select the element. Then it uses [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to append the option to the select.

```js
let dateArray = [{
    year: '2016',
    month: "01"
  },
  {
    year: '2017',
    month: "01"
  },
  {
    year: '2018',
    month: "02"
  },
  {
    year: '2018',
    month: "02"
  }
];
let select = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control")[0];

dateArray.forEach(e => {
  select.innerHTML += `<option key="${e.year}" value="${e.year}">${e.year}</option>`;
});
```

```html
<select class='form-control'>

</select>
```